# How do I get Index from listboxitem by its content?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listboxitem

Is there a way to get a Listbox Item Index by its content? Something like:

```
id = listbox.Items.Contains("text");
```

I know that this way I'll get a bool result, but I don't know how to get the item Index. If I could get the Index I could be able to remove items with

```
listbox.Items.RemoveAt(id);
```

Comment: Is is `ASP.Net` or `WindowsForms`?

Answer (score 2):

In WPF

```
ListBox listBox = new ListBox();   
int index = listBox.Items.IndexOf(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the item's index, and then you can remove it with the given method:

```
int index = myListBox.Items.IndexOf(itemToSearch); 
/*if there is no coincidence, it returns -1, so you must check for that return, else RemoveAt(-1) would give you a runtime error.*/
if (index >=0)
{
myListBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the item is not selected but for some reason you just want to find it in the list:

The listbox.items is a listbox object collection:
So:

```
id=listbox.items.IndexOf("text");
```

will do the trick.